# Excel Files on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, url, sharepoint-2010

I have a question regarding Excel VBA. I have multiple excel files located in a sharepoint folder. I need a macro that will combine these files into one document and has refresh capabilities. I have a code that works great when the excel files are on my D: drive, however I am not sure how to change my code if the files are now in a file on sharepoint.  The code has an error at the File Name stage. Does anyone know how to change my code below if the folder path is now a url?Any help would be great! Thanks so much!!!

```
    Sub copyOrRefreshSheet(destWb As Workbook, sourceWs As Worksheet)
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      On Error Resume Next
      Set ws = destWb.Worksheets(sourceWs.Name)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If ws Is Nothing Then
        sourceWs.Copy After:=destWb.Worksheets(destWb.Worksheets.Count)
      Else
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).Value = sourceWs.UsedRange.Value2
      End If
    End Sub

Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FolderPath = "D:\Users\jfreds\Desktop\temp folder\"  
Filename = Dir(FolderPath& "*.xls*")                                                             

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
copyOrRefreshSheet ThisWorkbook, Sheet
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening workbooks that are all in the same folder, then change FolderPath to:

`FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"`

I just tested this and it will open files in that folder even if they are on SharePoint. It will work where ever the folder is located. Another solution would be to sync that folder with OneDrive and then they will have a fixed path on your computer.

Edit: I got this to open and close two other `*.xlsx` workbooks and skip over the workbook with the macro. I am guessing that it has been saved as a `*.xlsm` workbook and would be picked up with `*.xls*`. I also had the Debug.Print in the wrong spot.

```
    Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()

    Dim FolderPath As String, Filename As String, TWB As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx") 'only will open *.xlsx files

Do While Filename <> ""
Debug.Print (Filename & " will open.")
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        Debug.Print(Filename & " is active.")
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            copyOrRefreshSheet ThisWorkbook, Sheet
        Next Sheet
        Debug.Print (Filename & " will close.")
        Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! I changed the folder path to what you have suggested since they are all in the same folder, however it is stating there is now an issue with the File Name (error 52). Do you know if there is something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `Debug.Print(Filename)` in the line below `Filename = Dir(FolderPath& "*.xls*")` to see what file is giving the error. I don't know if you are familiar  with Debug.Print, but it will print in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G in VBA Editor).

Comment: Sorry and a issue with Workbooks(Filename).Close (Error 9)

Comment: Did you try adding `SaveChanges:=False` after .Close? I was wondering what happens when it gets to the open workbook?

Comment: Hi Blake, I tried running it with the Debug.Print(Filename) however it is still stating the file name is incorrect and would not run.                                                       
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls")

Comment: Are all of the excel files in a newer excel format like *.xlsx or are they *.xls format? The issue here is in how the wildcard is used to select the files.

Comment: They are all xlsx. However if I change the extension the error persists. Should I remove the * as well?

Comment: Change `Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")` and see if there is one file that is causing the error by looking at the immediate window in the VBA editor.

Comment: I dont think the Dir() is working, I tried changing the filename, but I still get the Error 52.